# ReferenceError: mageplazaSearchProducts is not defined

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I have installed porto theme on Magento 2.3.5p1 version.

After installing theme it shows error like:

```
ReferenceError: mageplazaSearchProducts is not defined
```

I have checked that one file `default_0.js` created in

```
pub/media/mageplaza/search
```

but found that there is missing values for mageplazaSearchProducts.

```
var mageplazaSearchProducts =
```

can anyone suggest me how to solve this error ??

Answer (score 3):

Check data in `$productList` variable in `app/code/Mageplaza/Search/Helper/Data.php`. In my case, was the product description that was causing a encoding problem when trying to encode as json. Ended up wrapping the description in the [htmlentities](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) function

Comment: Thanks for answering. but its not working for me.

Comment: i have same issue facing any idea for that?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [@Gianr's answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/315159/47339) I managed to fix this by doing the following:

Place the `htmlentities` tag around the product description `$this->getProductDescription($product, $store)` in file `app/code/Mageplaza/Search/Helper/Data.php` somewhere around line `#230`.

Then rename the file `pub/media/mageplaza/search/default_0.js` to `xdefault_0.js`. Clear the cache and reload the page. A new `default_0.js` file should be generated WITH content. Problem solved!

Upvote if this fixed your problem plz!